# POST an array of strings from velocity to a struts ActionForm

Tags: java, struts, velocity

i m trying to retrive an array of String from a velocity template in a struts ActionForm:

my Html code :

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxAFF01" value="AFF01" name="expert[1]"> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxAFF02" value="AFF02" name="expert[2]"> 
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxAFF03" value="AFF03" name="expert[3]">
```

my ActionForm:

```
private String[] expert;

 public String getExpert(int index) {
   return expertise[index];
 }

 public void setExpert(int index, String value) {
   expertise[index] = value;
 }
```

but i m getting this error:

```
 2013-02-11 14:53:10,284 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/].[MainServlet] - "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet MainServlet  exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at .....setExpert(TestForm.java:115)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.setIndexedProperty(PropertyUtils.java:1435)
 at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:1013)
 at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:808)
 at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:495)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:798)
 at com.oroad.stxx.plugin.StxxTilesRequestProcessor.processPopulate(StxxTilesRequestProcessor.java:201)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:205)
 at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:149)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:415)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the indexed getters/setters and replace with a method that just gets and sets the array.

That said, I'd recommend using a list instead.

Comment: ok, this works for me :

    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxAFF01" value="AFF01" name="expert[]"> 
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxAFF02" value="AFF02" name="expert[]"> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxAFF03" value="AFF03" name="expert[]">
    
    
    public String[] getExpt() {
       return expert;
     }
    
     public void setExpert(String[] value) {
       this.expertise = value;
     }